# Using React Hooks for Data Provider and Data Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently reworking my `DataProvider`, updating it from a class component to a functional component with React Hooks.

I believe my issue is in the way I am setting up my context consumer but I haven't found a good way to test this.

DataProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";

const DataContext = createContext();

export const DataProvider = (props) => {
  const [test, setTest] = React.useState("Hello");

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={test}>{props.children}</DataContext.Provider>
  );
};
export const withContext = (Component) => {
  return function DataContextComponent(props) {
    return (
      <DataContext.Consumer>
        {(globalState) => <Component {...globalState} {...props} />}
      </DataContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
};
```

So my `withContext` function should receive a component and pass it the props  of the Context Provider.

I try to pull in my test state into a component.

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./DesktopAboutUs.module.css";
import { withContext } from "../../DataProvider";

const DesktopAboutUs = ({ test }) => {
  return (
    <div className={style.app}>
      <div>{test}</div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default withContext(DesktopAboutUs);
```

No data is showing up for `test`. To me this indicates that my `withContext` function is not properly receiving props from the `Provider`.

Comment: I think you meant `value={{test}}`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Why do you say so? What you said isn't right.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman `globalState` is `test`, which is a string and not an object when `value={test}`

Comment: Yes, I think the same, should be value={{test}}.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Ahhh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you passed `value={test}`, `globalState` is a string, not an object with a `test` property.

Either of these solutions will result in what you expected:

- Pass an object to the `value` prop of `DataContext.Provider` using `value={{ test }}` instead of `value={test}` if you intend `globalState` to contain multiple props.
- Pass `globalState` to the `test` prop of `Component` using `test={globalState}` instead of `{...globalState}` if you do not intend `globalState` to contain multiple props.

```js
const DataContext = React.createContext();

const DataProvider = (props) => {
  const [test, setTest] = React.useState("Hello");

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{ test }}>
      {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};

const withContext = (Component) => (props) => (
  <DataContext.Consumer>
    {(globalState) => <Component {...globalState} {...props} />}
  </DataContext.Consumer>
);

const DesktopAboutUs = ({ test }) => (
  <div>{test}</div>
);

const DesktopAboutUsWithContext = withContext(DesktopAboutUs);

ReactDOM.render(
  <DataProvider>
    <DesktopAboutUsWithContext />
  </DataProvider>,
  document.querySelector('main')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

Comment: I have tried updating `<DataContext.Provider value={{ test }}>` but I still am not able to receive this prop in my component.

Comment: @tdammon Is `<DataProvider>` actually in your virtual DOM? See my updated answer, works fine for me.